# Using function "buildGeometry" of JavaScript library JSTS with 'ol.interaction.Select' and 'ol.Collection.<ol.Feature>' objects?

Tags: openlayers, grouping, jsts, geometries

**What type is** the **argument of** a function **"buildGeometry" of JavaScript library JSTS?** How to use JSTS function "buildGeometry" with OpenLayers 3 selection, which is created is this way:

```js
window.select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    layers: window.layers, //an array of OpenLayers layers
    wrapX: false
});
```

According to [documentation](https://geoadmin.github.io/ol3/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html#getFeatures), the class 'ol.interaction.Select' has a method 'getFeatures', which returns 'ol.Collection.<ol.Feature>' object? A code:

```js
var features = window.select.getFeatures();
var geometryFactory = new jsts.geom.GeometryFactory();
var group = geometryFactory.buildGeometry(features);
```

causes an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.iterator is not a function
    buildGeometry (...)/js/openlayers3/jsts.js:9
```

**How to use JSTS** function **"buildGeometry" with** 'ol.interaction.Select' and **'ol.Collection.<ol.Feature>'** objects? How to create a group with various elements which are selected with OpenLayers 3?

Comment: I presume you would need to parse the feature geometry into JSTS format with `jsts.io.OL3Parser` as in https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/jsts.html
e.g. `var geometries = select.getFeatures().getArray().map(function(feature) { return parser.read(feature.getGeometry()); });`  Note that in more recent versions of JSTS you must inject the OpenLayers format constructors into the parser.